# Former employer asking for SSN and DOB

Tags: email

A former employer is asking my wife for her SSN and DOB in email to report to Workplace. Is that is true? 
Can we provide my SSN and DOB directly to Workplace instead of going through the former employer?

Comment: What is workplace?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. 1) What is "workplace?" 2) you say **your** former employer is asking for your **wife's** SSN but you're asking about providing **your** SSN (not your wife's, which you say they're asking for).

Comment: [edit: nevermind.  I was thinking of Work*day*.] Workplace is a payroll/time tracking/general HR app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Former employer?

They should have that information already. Why would you give it out again? Why do they "need" it? Until you get a good reason, just ignore their request, it's not your problem.

Comment: Just be sure you have that last paystub handy showing all deductions withheld.

Comment: Sounds fishy to me. Any former employer that doesn't have your SSN but still has to file reports on you is breaking records retention laws or is (more likely) full of crap.

Comment: And do not ever send that sort of sensitive info in email!